# Swift - RemoveAllAnimations() doesn't work in an UICollectionViewCell class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation

I currently have the problem that removeAllAnimations() function does not work in my custom UICollectionViewCell class.

The array progressBar[] includes multiple UIProgressViews. I want the progressBar to stop animating when something is called. But right now it just keeps on animating.
How can I fix this?

First function which does the actual animation

```
@objc func updateProgress() {
    if visibleCell == "TRUE" {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if self.index < self.imagesTest.count /*images.count*/ {
                CATransaction.begin()
                CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
                    self.index += 1
                    self.updateProgress()
                }
                UIView.animate(withDuration: self.time, delay: 0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
                    self.progressBar[self.index].setProgress(1.0, animated: true)
                })
                CATransaction.commit()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Second function which should stop the ongoing animation

```
func stopUpdating() {
    progressBar[index].layer.removeAllAnimations()
}
```

Comment: remove the progressbar instead of animating from the view

Comment: But then the progressBar won't be shown anymore, right? And I just want the animation to stop/cancel.

Comment: use   progressBar[index].layer.speed = 0

Comment: thanks! I can work with your solution. @Prashant Tukadiya

Comment: @JoshSchärer Glad that solution works, I am posting it as answer so other also can take help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that with single line of code

Replace your code

```
func stopUpdating() {
    progressBar[index].layer.removeAllAnimations()
}
```

With

```
func stopUpdating() {
   progressBar[index].layer.speed = 0 
}
```

Hope it is helpful to you